# Textbox too wide in edge's label when using tikz-network

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, labels, network

I am new at using tikz-network, however I find this interesting. When I do

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta}
        \Vertex[label=a,fontscale=1.3,size=1.5]{a}
        \Vertex[label=b,fontscale=1.3,size=1.5,x=0,y=-4]{b}
        \Vertex[label=$u_1$,fontscale=1.3,x=-3,y=-6]{U1}
        \Vertex[label=$u_n$,fontscale=1.3,x=3,y=-6]{UN}
        %
        \Edge[style={dashed},bend=-25,label={$u_2,\ldots, u_{n-1}$},fontscale=1.3](U1)(UN)
        %
        \Edge[style={latex-latex},label={$E_{u,g}^h$, $E_{g,u}^h$},fontscale=1.3](a)(b)
        \Edge[Direct,label={$E_{u_1,g}^h$, $E_{g,u_1}^h$},fontscale=1.3](U1)(b)
        \Edge[Direct,label={$E_{u_n,g}^h$, $E_{g,u_n}^h$},fontscale=1.3](UN)(b)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the edges' labels are in a white box which is too wide and covers the corresponding edges. I also tried with some parameters (`InnerSep`) remarked in the manual (with `\SetEdgesStyle`, `\SetTextStyle`) but I can't achieve what I want. Ah, btw, everything is in Overleaf. Any suggestion?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please post a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that it is clear which packages and libraries you load.

Comment: Please make it a habbit to start your code with `\documentclass{ `, provide (only) relevant packages you use, and provide all that's needed until `\end{document} ` . Makes things easier for all involved.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Hi, I apologize, now I think I have fixed the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the appearance of labels on edges by editing the default `EdgeLabelStyle`, which is defined as (here you can see that the white box is actually a circle):

```
\tikzset{EdgeLabelStyle/.style={circle,
                               fill           = \cmdNW@DES@TextFillColor,
                               fill opacity   = \cmdNW@DES@TextFillOpacity,
                               inner sep      = \cmdNW@DES@InnerSep,
                               outer sep      = \cmdNW@DES@OuterSep,
                               rotate         = \cmdNW@DES@TextRotation,
                               text opacity   = \cmdNW@DES@TextOpacity,
                               font           = \cmdNW@DES@TextFont}}
}%
```

So, you could do the following:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-network}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{EdgeLabelStyle/.append style={
    rectangle,
    inner sep=3pt     % or change via \EdgeInnerSep
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Vertex[label=a,fontscale=1.3,size=1.5]{a}
    \Vertex[label=b,fontscale=1.3,size=1.5,x=0,y=-4]{b}
    \Vertex[label=$u_1$,fontscale=1.3,x=-3,y=-6]{U1}
    \Vertex[label=$u_n$,fontscale=1.3,x=3,y=-6]{UN}
    %
    \Edge[style={dashed},bend=-25,label={$u_2,\ldots, u_{n-1}$},fontscale=1.3](U1)(UN)
    %
    \Edge[style={latex-latex},label={$E_{u,g}^h$, $E_{g,u}^h$},fontscale=1.3](a)(b)
    \Edge[Direct,label={$E_{u_1,g}^h$, $E_{g,u_1}^h$},fontscale=1.3](U1)(b)
    \Edge[Direct,label={$E_{u_n,g}^h$, $E_{g,u_n}^h$},fontscale=1.3](UN)(b)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And you can add ` position=below` , or right etc. to your option list from Edge.